# Calculating Percentage in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to calculate percentage in Python, by hand this works fine but in python this formula for some reason does not work.  I tried multiple ways but just not getting correct results.

```
getPercent = lambda part, whole: float(1 - (float(part)/float(part))) * 100
Val1= float(3194.15)
Val2= float(3163.84)
getPercent(Val2, Val1)
```

Output:
0.0

output should be:
0.95

Comment: You're dividing `part` by `part`, rather than `whole`.

Comment: Also, the result is not 95%, more like 99.05%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `whole` instead of `part` in the denominator.

```python
getPercent = lambda part, whole: float(1 - (float(part)/float(whole))) * 100
Val1= float(3194.15)
Val2= float(3163.84)
getPercent(Val2, Val1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwFET3PcUs86W2/aaKFnoHV@6jRiukSQgfxNNHYoXuhpk3M/EjU/A656eVs0036wUjnJmvd4NoktR4T8HZAQ8XjCjGFmqRJaV20T@GiLABd111MY7Hf0PzqW94T8XcreZBN8eeqpheXtR6rgpVowwQ5fwF)

Comment: You can save a few bytes by getting rid of all those `float` calls.

Comment: Oh yes, I just fixed OP's code, didn't mean to improve it. :-)

Comment: (I was referring to the --now removed-- Code-Golf header :-P )

Comment: Ah, I see. I was in a hurry, heh.

Comment: Thanks you, I actually tried few version and no idea how I messed that up.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't used `whole` in your lambda function

```
getPercent = lambda part, whole: float(1 - (float(part)/float(whole))) * 100
Val1= float(3194.15)
Val2= float(3163.84)
getPercent(Val2, Val1)
# output 0.9489222484855064
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide by `whole`. To get just two decimal places:

```
get_percent = lambda part, whole: float(1 - part / whole) * 100

val_1 = float(3194.15)
val_2 = float(3163.84)
a_float = get_percent(val_2, val_1)

print("{:.2f}".format(a_float))
```

Returning:

```
0.95
```